# Do branches of logarithms matter over real numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Suppose I start with $ln(x)$ where $x$ is a strictly real variable.  Other complex branches of $ln(x)$ are merely separated by an imaginary constant $2 i \pi k$. This seems to suggest that for all branches, the real line $x$ is mapped the same while it is only the imaginary component that changes. If this is true, then for purely real inputs of $x$, is it true that $ln(x) = ln(x)+2 i \pi k$? I feel like it shouldn't be quite that simple. and yet if I take the exponent, $$e^{ln(x)+2 \pi i k} = e^{ln(x)}e^{2 \pi i k}= e^{ln(x)}(1) = x$$ $x$ is always returned. If that's true, then does it follow that
$$e^{log(x)}+e^{log(x)+2 i \pi k} = x+x = 2x?$$ with no special domain restrictions beyond x being positive?

Also, what if k isn't an integer?

Comment: $f(x) = \ln(x) + 2i \pi k$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ is the only way to have a continuous (and analytic) function $f :\mathbb{R}^+ \to f(\mathbb{R}^+)$ such that $e^{f(x)} = x$. With $k \not\in \mathbb{Z}$ you'll have $e^{f(x)} = x e^{2i \pi k}$. There are many more non-continuous functions such as $\ln(x) + 2i \pi 1_{x > 1}$.

Answer (score 2):

If it seems too simple, remember it's not much different than asking for $\arccos(x)$.  When you've found one answer, you can add any integer multiple of $2\pi$ and get another answer.

This is because $\cos(x)$ is $2\pi$-periodic along the real line.  In other words, $\cos(x+2\pi k) = \cos(x)$ for integer $k$.  By comparison, $e^{z}$ is $2\pi$-periodic but "only in the complex direction."  If you take $e^{z+2\pi k}$ you won't get the same thing as $e^{z}$.  But, if you take $e^{z+2\pi i k}$ you will get the same thing.

---

Edit: let me try to directly answer each of the questions directly, at risk of getting into semantics.

1. Does $ln(x) = ln(x)+2 i \pi k$ for real $x$?  **No.**  The same way $\sin^{-1}(1/2) \neq \sin^{-1}(1/2)+2\pi$.  It happens that $\pi/6$ and $13\pi/6$ define "coterminal" angles, but they are different numbers.  Since the principal branch of $\sin$ is $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ I say that $\sin^{-1}(1/2) = \pi/6$ even though $\sin(13\pi/6) = 1/2$ as well.  The principal branch for $\ln$ is a 2d region since it is in the complex plane.  It is where $-\pi \leq \operatorname{Im}(z) \leq \pi$ and $z \neq 0$.
2. Is it true that $$e^{log(x)}+e^{log(x)+2 i \pi k} = x+x = 2x?$$  **Yes.**  Just like $$\sin(\sin^{-1}(x)) + \sin(\sin^{-1}(x) + 2\pi) = x + x = 2x.$$  Neither $e^{z}$ nor $\sin(x)$ are one-to-one functions, so there are multiple inputs that produce the same results.
3. What if $k$ isn't an integer?  $e^{\ln(x) + 2\pi i k}$ gives you $x$ (positive real number, lying on the real axis) rotated by $k$ revolutions about the origin in the complex plane.  So if $k$ is an integer, you have a whole number of revolutions and you end up where you started.  If $k$ is not an integer, you will end up at some other $z\in\mathbb{C}$ where $|z| = x$.

Comment: Okay, so, does this prove that for any positive real number x, that $ln(x) = ln(x)+2 i \pi k$? Because this isn't the same as the arccos problem, I'm not asking $f(x+2i \pi k)$, I'm asking about $f(x)+2 \pi ik.$. In a very particular way it's true that arccos(x)+2*pi = arccos(x), but that's only if arccos(x) is no longer a function, otherwise you don't get the right numbers when you assume arccos(x)+2*pi=arccos(x) since it becomes complex above and below its branch points.

Comment: Let's just start with the exponential property. So no matter what branch I have, it's always true that $e^{ln(x)+2* i \pi k} = x$ at least for positive values of x? So there's no special domain restrictions, I can have something like $e^{log(x)}+e^{log(x)+2 i \pi k} = x+x = 2x$?

Comment: I mentioned that $ln$ is not periodic in the "real direction".  That is, if you are just thinking about real $x$ and looking for a real result, the familiar value you are looking for is just the value of $\ln(x)$ your pocket calculator will tell you.  _But_ note that you can take this real value of $\ln(x)$ and add integer multiples of $2\pi i$ and you will get other complex numbers $z$ such that $e^z = x$.

Comment: Can you actually directly answer the questions I asked though? It seems like you're dodging them for some reason. Can you at least give a "yes" or "no"? For instance does the algebra in the third equation of the OP work?

Comment: It doesn't seem like it's actually true because you get a contradiction. You keep bringing up e^z for some reason, but I would be working with e^x. It's not true that ln(x) = ln(x) + 2*pi*i, so the algebra I asked about shouldn't work even though you said it does, because taking the log of both sides of $e^{ln(x)} = e^{ln(x)+2 \pi i}$ reduces to $ln(x) = ln(x)+2 \pi i$ which we already agreed isn't true.

Comment: What is the contradiction?  I'm using $z$ to represent complex numbers and $x$ to represent real numbers.  I'm talking about $e^z$ where $z = \ln(x) + 2\pi i k$ as you requested.

Comment: I'm talking about the contradiction I just mentioned. We both agree $ln(x) \neq ln(x) + 2 \pi i$, but you said it's true that $e^{ln(x)+2 \pi i k} = e^{ln(x)} = x$, but now it can't true be because taking the log of both sides of $e^{ln(x)} = e^{ln(x)+2 \pi i}$ reduces to $ln(x) = ln(x) + 2 \pi i$ which we already agreed isn't true. It's like pretending $x = x+1$ has a solution, but you get the contradiction $0 = 1$. In this case we get the contradiction $0 = 2 \pi i$ which as you already said are two different numbers.

Comment: By your logic I could prove $9 = -9$.  It's true that $9^2 = (-9)^2$ but I can't "cancel" the square on both sides.  If I take the square root of both sides (both 81) I get $9 = 9$, not $9 = -9$.

Comment: By my logic it actually wouldn't be true because I'm proving that it's a contradiction to assume it's true. So like I said, there is some special domain or branch choice property you keep avoiding for some reason that would resolve the issue. if you take the square root of both sides you get +/-9 = +/-9. It does absolutely "cancel" the square, that's the whole point of taking a square root. You cancel the square and you are left with the possible values that could have been squared to equal 81.

Comment: It seems like you do understand and are just worrying about semantics.  From wiki: " the designation 'the square root' is often used to refer to the principal square root." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root

Comment: No it's not semantics its an actual problem. I do not see how to make use of if $e^{log(x)} = e^{log(x)+2 \pi i}$ then it still isn't true that $ln(x) = ln(x) + 2 \pi i$ because all I did to get $ln(x) = ln(x) + 2 \pi i$ was take the log of both sides which is a valid move algebraically.

Comment: Sure, if you think of $\ln(x)$ as the set $\{z:e^z = x\}$ then if you add $2\pi i$ to every element of this set you get the same set back.  You could write $ \ln(x) \equiv \{z:e^z = x\}$, $\ln(x)+2\pi i \equiv \{z + 2\pi i:z\in \ln(x)\}$, and then $\ln(x) = \ln(x) + 2\pi i$ would be correct.  But you'd have to think of $\ln$ as a set-valued function which is non-standard.

Comment: "sure why not?" just doesn't help at all. If I have an equation $f(x) = x(x+2\pi i)$. Using a u substitution and back substituting should yield the same result as other methods. If I were to solve for x, or finding the inverse function, traditional algebra would yield the result as $ x= \pm \sqrt{f(x)- \pi^{2}}-i \pi $. However, if I were to make the substitution $u = e^x$, the problem then becomes $f(u) = ln(u)(ln(u)+2 \pi i)$. Exponentiating both sides and selecting the $ln(u)+2 \pi i$ to be canceled would leave $f(u) = u^{ln(u)}$, yielding $x = \sqrt{f(x)}$ as the result which is incorrect.

Comment: So what should be done differently to make that u-substitution work?